# Using Match in Jquery return just one value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

I'm trying to use "Match" to filter some values in my textarea but my code only works for the first line, returning just "one.png;1".

I need to get all values in "text2" div, like: "one.png;1 / two.png;2 / three.png;3"

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var dataimg = $('#text').text().match('url_image="(.*)";');
  var datasub = $('#text').text().match('sub=(.*);');

  $("#text2").append(dataimg[1]).append(";").append(datasub[1]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">

  url_image="one.png"; sub=1; url_image="two.png"; sub=2; url_image="three.png"; sub=3;

</div>

<div id="text2"></div>
```

Anyone here who can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to update the formatting of the text, then you can use a global replace such as:

```
/url_image="([^"]+)"; sub=(.*);/g
```

And replace the matches with `'$1;$2'`:

```js
$('#text2').text(function () {
  return $('#text').text().replace(/url_image="([^"]+)"; sub=(.*);/g, '$1;$2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text" style="display: none">
url_image="one.png"; sub=1; 
url_image="two.png"; sub=2; 
url_image="three.png"; sub=3;
</div>

<div id="text2"></div>
```

---

Of course you could also use the global `g` flag with the [`.match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), but if you want to retrieve all the captured groups, you need to use the [`.exec()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```js
var text = $('#text').text();
var regex = /url_image="([^"]+)"; sub=(.*);/g;
var updatedText = '';
var match;

while ((match = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
    if (match.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    updatedText += match[1] + ';' + match[2];    
}

$('#text2').text(updatedText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="text" style="display: none">
url_image="one.png"; sub=1; 
url_image="two.png"; sub=2; 
url_image="three.png"; sub=3;
</div>

<div id="text2"></div>
```